# Will a mini pci-e sata card work on a laptop?

Tags: laptop, sata, pci-express, ubuntu-server

Recently I converted an old HP ProBook 4440s laptop that had no use for years into a mini nas for me. I was wondering how much can I do with this laptop so I wanna give it 16gb of ram and more storage space. So searching a little I saw this card:

It uses a mini pci-e connection, same as the wifi card. I was wondering if would be possible to change the wifi card of the laptop for this card so I can make a proper nas.
Things to consider:

- The "laptop" part is long gone, only the pcb sits in a drawer of my home, so the space will not represent a problem.
- It had a dvd player, can I plug another hard drive there?
- It has ubuntu server as its OS.

Comment: Generally, the PCIe slot for a WiFi card on a laptop can only be used for a WiFi card, and the HP ProBook 4440s can definitely only use it for that since it's a [PCIe 1x1 slot](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03356342#AbT3). If you have an mini PCIe card slot on the exterior of the laptop casing, that might be able to be used for a HDD, but even that's unlikely. Even on laptops with more than 1x1 PCIe lanes, those lanes are usually already being used for drives, USB ports, networking, etc. _(this [article](https://www.techspot.com/article/2664-pci-express-explained/) explains it more)_